Logged out suddenly, twice
On desktop, my session is usually pretty stable; I only see myself logged out on domains I'm not active on, like mathoverflow.com. However, twice so far today (over a span of no more than 2 hours), I've been logged out of SE entirely. The first time triggered the dark mode bug. The second time was in the middle of a chat conversation and resulted in my message suddenly giving an error instead of sending.
Given the maintenance last night, I'm wondering if this is a widespread problem.

The session closures I'm seeing for you indicate CookieTokenDoesNotMatch ("account session was deemed invalid"). I'm not sure what would contribute to your token no longer matching, but just wanted to clarify that this is not related to the recent maintenance - all that changed was the location of the OpenID database, and the database is only touched on initial authentication anyway (so even if the database disappeared mid-session, it wouldn't affect you, for the same reason relevant maintenance windows don't impact existing active sessions).

Try to disable all browser extensions, add-ons, and userscripts. Try with a different browser. Might be something in the browser that messed with the cookies/tokens.

When I tried to open Meta now, I was also logged out. But the timing is different, as I visited this question yesterday and all was good.

I was suddenly logged out again today, just after I have sent a mod message and page reloaded. The frequency of this sudden log -outs has increased and now I am logged out few times a month. I visit sites every day and this kind of things never happened before SE started to meddle with Google login (which I am not using) I used to be logged in for years.

@ResistanceIsFutile I suspect it's about their switch to CloudFlare, and setting more and more blocks on the traffic between SE and us, the users.

@ShadowWizard Wouldn't CloudFlare show some other message, than just log out user that is accessing the site through browser? My initial issues started when they introduced Google login and this was the time I experienced first automatic logout. I initially though that this happened because they changed some cookies or similar, but it still happens regularly and more frequently. I am not saying that some other measures besides new login are not the culprit.

@ResistanceIsFutile well, I mean CloudFlare might mess behind the scenes with something that is required for the login to "stick", not a direct request. And when the system identify a "blip" it would initiate log out, e.g. I remember a case long ago where having wrong local time caused log out. Of course totally different, but still - something might interfere behind the scenes, and my suspect falls on CloudFlare. I didn't have any issues since the Google login change, but of course - we can't really know. :/

@ShadowWizard Yeah, anything is possible. I am not ruling out CloudFlare either. But I am also not really an expert in all this... basically what I can say is "it is broken, please fix" ;)
